# Problems with C operators

Tags: c, operators

I have this code:

```
long long int a = 3, *b = &a;
int c = !(a+=1, a>>=2, a--, !a);
printf ("%11d %d\n", a, c);
```

when I run it, it gave me 0 0, but I don't understand why. Shouldn't be 0 1?

Comment: Google for "c sequence point".

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: the comma operator is a sequence point, so this is NOT UB.

Comment: Note that `%11d` should be `%lld` and the declaration of `b` is redundant.

Comment: This artificial code is not useful to future SO users/visitors.

Comment: @PaulR I thought of that after I posted and forgot to come back and remove my comment. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 4):

Expand the code and remove anything redundant:

```
long long int a = 3;         // a = 3
a+=1;                        // a = 4
a>>=2;                       // a = 1
a--;                         // a = 0
int c = !!a;                 // c = 0
printf ("%lld %d\n", a, c);  // prints 0 0
          ^^
      // note that this should be `ll`, not `11`
```

Answer (score 3):

This code uses the comma operator, which evaluates the operations in order and then evaluates to the last one.

```
int a = 3;
a += 1;             // a = 4
a >>= 2;            // a = 1
a--;                // a = 0
int c = !(..., !a); // c = !(!a) = !(!0) = 0
```

By the way for those in doubt -

> The comma operator introduces a sequence point, and therefore in the
>   code f(),g() the order of evaluation is defined: first f() is called,
>   and then g() is called.